# Where should I ask a question about my career?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need to ask a question about what path to follow and what knowledge must be acquired to land a job in a certain big company? (Knowing the requirements of the job position aren't enough to tell you how to go about acquiring them.)

Comment: Can you explain a little about the field it is in? If it's an academic or research field, it could go on Academia.SE, otherwise it might fit in with a site with the same subject area.

Answer (score 5):

*Some* questions about [careers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/careers/info) are welcome at [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/). However, I fear they would close your question as it stands;

> Questions asking for **advice on a specific choice**, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else. Instead of asking which decision to make, try asking how to make the decision, or for more specific details about one element of the decision.

From [their Meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/33983):

> When people ask us for personalized advice, a lot of the specific details will not apply to other people who come across the question since their details may be slightly different and they can't determine whether or not the answer is appropriate for their situation. It's also hard to answer these questions objectively; we're not looking for collections of unsupported opinions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although it is a bit unfortunate that the question might be closed there, given that I already made up my mind as of which company i want to join but still need advice on what steps to follow, given that the world of technology is ever changing, same as the company's goals